# How to invalidate() a View from another thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, view, invalidation

I've got a couple of Views that are updated once a second by a Timer task. They can't `invalidate()` themselves because "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views".

There is a function called [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for this, but I need an Activity to run it.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: Is this what `postInvalidate()` is for? How guaranteed am I that the invalidation and update will happen soon (if the UI thread isn't busy)?

Comment: why you use a Timer (and a Thread behind it) for such a trivial task? use Handler instead

Comment: @pskink The Timer is mocking a bluetooth listener thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

> Is this what postInvalidate() is for?

Yes

[According to the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29)

> Use this to invalidate the View from a non-UI thread.

`invalidate()` is for updating `Views` on the `UI Thread`

2)

> How guaranteed am I that the invalidation and update will happen soon
>   (if the UI thread isn't busy)?

Also from that same part of the docs

> Cause an invalidate to happen on a subsequent cycle through the event loop

So I guess this depends on your definition of "soon". As the docs say it should happen on the next event loop